# How to do full version control on OneDrive (with git?)

Tags: git, onedrive, cloud-storage, version

I'm using OneDrive to store all sorts of files (not just Office files).  Unfortunately, versioning isn't supported except for Office files. I'd like to do this manually, with git or svn or anything else.  How can I do that?

Comment: You could run a local git or svn repository I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bvckup 2 (last free is free https://bvckup2.com/get/beta)

You can keep backups of files and set to delete them after so many days.

You could for example, set the delete time to 30 days.

[image]